How to treat shadows in relativity?
So, I came across this question in special relativity, and while attempting to solve it I got confused about shadows.

A point source of light is at a height of $2h$ above an infinite flat horizontal plane. A pointlike rocketship flies by at a speed of $U_{ship} = 0.5c$ relative to the light, parallel to the plane, and at a height of $h$ above it with a trajectory so that it will pass directly under the light. The time interval, in the rest frame of the light source, between the ship being directly under the light and the shadow being directly under the ship is $ah/c$. Find $a$.

So, here, how do we treat the shadow? Like, can somoene give me the approach for solving this problem? Do we treat the shadow as an absence of light like when the ship is physically directly under the source, or what?
edit: I have since concluded that the spaceship and and shadow appear to be in same position in light sources frame when the spaceship moves to the right and then in the time the light takes to form  the shadow to the down right of the spaceship it reaches the point vertically abv it. But I am unable to proceed further mathamatically. Canm someone help

The shadow's world-volume is the set of spacetime events which would have received a photon from the source if the ship had not flown by.

in this scenario, you can treat the shadow as "propagating" at speed $c$.

the statement "flying at 0.5 c relative to light" indicates a major problem. The whole point of relativity is that you are always moving at 0 relative to light.

@JEB Relative to the light (source).

@JEB it seems the measured ratio $c=\frac{d}{t}$ can also remain constant if assuming a universal clock. Suppose ship is 5 lightseconds from a starbase. It sends a light pulse & as soon as the starbase detects this pulse it sends a return pulse back. The ship will receive the return pulse when it has travelled $3\frac{1}{3}$ lightseconds. The total two-way distance travelled by the light is $6\frac{2}{3}$ lightseconds. The universal clock will have ticked $2(3\frac{1}{3})=6\frac{2}{3}$ times, because the speed of ship is 0.5 light speed. So $c=\frac{d}{t}=\frac{6\frac{2}{3}}{6\frac{2}{3}}=1$.

okay so how  do i actually approach the solving o this problem ?

HELLO ?why is no one replying ? @James

Because relativistic raytracing is hard!  At least, not simple enough to do justice to in an answer here, I would say.

by answer here u mean answer on the stackexchange platform ? or in the comments

@SUI i recommend drawing a sketch of the setup, in the rest frame of the lamp. You then have two cases, (1) where the ship is directly under the lamp, and (2) where the shadow is directly under the ship. As the ship passes the lamp, it is being trailed by its shadow, but the trailing velocity depends on the angle between the perpendicular from the lamp onto the plane and the line connecting the lamp and the ship. Note that the "trailing velocity" does not have an upper bound. Can you solve it now?

i did i found that the the shift must be say a distance x frm the centre then the light has to cover sqrt(x^2 + h^2) in ground frame so time in ground fram will be t' = [sqrt(x^2 + h^2)]/c then using lorentz transforms transforming this equation to the S' frame and from there getting x' and then re transforming that to S frame is what i think i shuld be doing but my math isnt right ? Please help

@SUI Sorry I had not thought about your problem, my comment was directed at the statement "the whole point of relativity is that you are always moving at 0 relative to light"
